# How do I make my command line use a specific version of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, command-line, zappa

I am getting started on using Zappa. However, I already had installed python 3.7 on my computer while Zappa uses 3.6. I installed python 3.6.8, but when I try to use zappa in the cmd (zappa init) it uses python 3.7 by default. How can I direct zappa to use 3.6 instead?

Comment: If you are working on Linux or MacOS you can modify the PATH variable to python3.6 be on begin.

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota I'm on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Zappa [README](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#installation-and-configuration):

> Please note that Zappa must be installed into your project's virtual environment.

You should use something like `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment, which makes it easy to switch Python version.

If you use virtualenv, you can try create an environment by:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv
$ source activate venv
```

Then `pip install zappa` in this virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Zappa, but if you want use a specific version of python can do:

```
python3.6 my_program.py
```

and if whant use the command *python* with a specific version permanently, in **linux** modify the file */home/[user_name]/.bashrc* and add the next line:

```
alias python=python3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualenv` to setup an environment using a specific Python version by:

```
% pip install virtualenv
% virtualenv -p python3.6 .venv
```

You can also use an absolute path to the Python executable if it's named the same but located in different folders.

Then switch to use the environment:

```
% source .venv/bin/activate
```

This environment uses Python 3.6, so install Zappa with pip like normal and you're good to go.

You can read more about usage of virtualenv [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000695551-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-3).